# Can you determine column-width in iText based on input (e.g. a string)?

Tags: java, itext, pdfptable

I am working on a project using iText and Java. In the project, I will be making a pdf. In this pdf, there will be multiple tables and they will have changing column counts and content, which means the column-widths have to be determined in a flexible way too.

A lot works well so far, but I am stuck on the whole column-width issue. My current attempt is to determine them based on a database-entry. So let's say I have 2 columns, and I want one to be 20 % of the table size and the other 80 %. Then if I did it manually, I would just have to write the following code:

```
table.setWidths(new float[] { 20, 80 });
```

or

```
table.setWidths(new int[] { 20, 80 });
```

An example of my failed attempts is when I use this data-entry:

> 20, 80

And then I attempt to make the entry into a float or int through parsing it as a string to a float, but of course it gives me a parsing error.

Does anyone have a fix for my current problem or got an idea for how to approach a new solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was needed was to split the string into an int[], like so:

```
String inputFromDatabase = "1,5";
String[] p = inputFromDatabase.trim().split(",");
int[] ans = new int[p.length];
for (int a = 0; a < p.length; a++) {
    ans[a] = Integer.parseInt(p[a]);
}
table.setWidths(ans);
```

The answer was found [here](https://lemire.me/blog/2017/08/31/parsing-comma-separated-integers-in-java/)